# CSS/HTML - Line appears at bottom of page

Tags: html, css

I am working on a site and have a solid line appearing at the bottom of the page.

**The Problem:** http://jsfiddle.net/mxh6G/

**The Details:** I have a container element which has `height: 99%;`.  I have also set up a gradient background effect (using only CSS).  Now, beneath my main `container` element, there is a block of solid colour which matches the colour of the upper half of the gradient fill.  However, please note that this is not what is causing the problem as even when I remove the gradient section of the CSS altogether, the blank line is still visible (I have set the `background-color:` of my `container` element to red so that I can see if the problem still persists).

For example, if the gradient fades from red (top) to black (bottom), the solid line at the bottom of the page is red.

I have set the height to 100% and even up to 150% for my `container` element and the solid line is still there.

An example might be like this:

```
+----------------------+
|   _________________  |
|  |        C       |  |
|  |        O       |  |
|  |        N       |  |
|  |        T       |  |
|  |        A       |  |
|  |        I       |  |
|  |        N       |  |
|  |        E       |  |
|  |        R       |  |
+______________________|
|______________________| <--- solid line appears here 
                              (but narrower, approx 5px in height).
```

Hopefully this gives you all a rough idea of what the problem is.

My HTML is absolutely fine - I have checked it thoroughly and there are no elements outside of the container `<div>` element.

I know that there could be any number of solutions, so to simplify things, I would like to ask if there are any commonly-known (or not-so-commonly-known) problems related to CSS which could cause this to happen?

Or, better still, has anybody else had this problem and if so, how did you rectify it (if applicable)?

Thanks for your time.

Mick

**UPDATE:** Here is the problem: I have set the top margin of `container` to 5px and it results in the bottom of the page also displaying a 5px margin from the bottom.  If I set it to 0, however, then the margin at the bottom of the page is also set to 0.

Could somebody possibly figure out why this is happening?

(NOTE: You have to extend the frames outwards to view the page as it is intended and to also see the problem).

http://jsfiddle.net/mxh6G/

Comment: I have not seen this before, could you provide a testcase on [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) that shows the same issue?

Comment: Sure, I have just added the jsfiddle link. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is, that you are using %'s to judge your size, then applying a margin to it. ie. 100% height (for example is 100px;) then your applying a 5px margin on it, taking the total height to 105px (105%), thats why your getting scroll bars appearing...

Comment: Thank you, I think that's pretty much solved it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set this in css

```
body{margin:0; padding:0;}
```

or

```
* {margin:0; padding:0;}
```

Comment: `* {margin:0; padding;}` is not a good idea. It causes unnecessary work for the browser.

Comment: One thing that I forgot to mention - I would like a 5px margin at the top of my `container`; however, whenever I set this, it generates a margin of the same height at the bottom of the page, too.  Any ideas on how to resolve this?  Thanks.

Comment: You would have to set it just to your container in css #container{margin-top:5px;}

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this is what I did and it generated a margin of the same width below.  i.e. if I set `margin-top: 1px`, then a margin of 1px appears at the bottom of the page, too.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Then your doing something wrong... Ill make a demo for you now

Comment: Added for you now on this page :) Remember to vote it up if its of help to you :)

Comment: @Graeme Leighfield Thank you for your effort.  I have posted a link to the problem so that you can see exactly what happens (http://jsfiddle.net/mxh6G/).  Feel free to play around with it and let me know your thoughts.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This renders a black page (so you can see no margin at the bottom) with a white inner div called container, with a 5px margin on the top

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html>

    <head>

        <style>
            body {margin:0; padding:0; background:#000;}
            #container {width:600px; height:600px; margin:5px auto 0 auto; background:#fff;}
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="container"></div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for this - here is the problem if you would like to take a look at it. http://jsfiddle.net/mxh6G/

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
border: 1px solid black;
}
.main {
position: relative;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
}
.inner {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
height: 30px; 
}

<div class="main">dasdasd<div class="inner">fdsfds</div></div>
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/JS2y2/